# Как подсчитать количество непустых полей img*?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица постов в блоге:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `img1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img3` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img4` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img5` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img6` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img7` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img8` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img9` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `img10` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Как получить средством MySQL кол-во непустых полей в каждой строке?

Comment: В чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Что уже сделано для того, чтобы посчитать эти непустые значения?

Comment: дубликаты (от имени других пользователей): [1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435413/178576) и [2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435277/178576)

Comment: Структуру базы переделать по-человечески...

Comment: Пожалуйста, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа). Это поможет другим пользователям сайта.

Comment: @Сергей, если вы только начали создание  блога - переделайте таблицу, как люди советуют...   если вы лишь сопровождаете уже кем-то написанный проект - вам можно только посочувствовать (но лучше переделайте...  и опыт получите и понимание как надо и как не надо делать)

Answer (score 4):

Вариант 1:

```
select 
    if(img1!='', 1, 0)
    + if(img2!='', 1, 0)   
    + if(img3!='', 1, 0)
    + if(img4!='', 1, 0)
    + if(img5!='', 1, 0)   
    + if(img6!='', 1, 0)
    + if(img7!='', 1, 0)
    + if(img8!='', 1, 0)   
    + if(img9!='', 1, 0)
    + if(img10!='', 1, 0)
    as Cnt
from blog
```

Вариант 2: написать функцию mysql

Вариант 3: обрабатывать на стороне вызывающего кода

Comment: Вариант 4: (уже выше писали) переделать нормально БД - картинки выносим в отдельную таблицу и ссылаемся на блог по `id`. Пожалуй, этот вариант будет самым правильным

Answer (score 0):

Подсказки:

- раз поля не могут быть `NULL`, что очень хорошо, их заполненность можно оценить функцией MySQL [`LENGTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) – она вернёт `0` для пустых полей в вашем случае, и какое-то положительное целое для заполненных.
- функция [`SIGN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_sign) возвращает знак аргумента: `1` для положительных, `-1` для отрицательных и `0` если ноль.